# Code not working properly for fetching particular embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have a collection HostelTbl like

```
 {
 "_id": ObjectId("5ae845b3d2ccda137000595d"),
 "Name": "abc",
 "Address": "gggswwrerghyjh",
 "NoOfFloors": NumberInt(4),
 "Approved": "Yes",
 "SchoolId": ObjectId("5a8e9025ff24ae113c005d42"),
 "RoomsDetails": [
  {
     "RoomId": "80a1761f-f8ee-a78f-c6ab-6f9bfbdb8ea3",
     "FloorNumber": "3",
     "RoomNumber": "5",
     "RoomType": ObjectId("5ae8267ed2ccda137000595b"),
     "NumberOfBeds": "4" 
   },
    {
     "RoomId": "56a1761f-f8ee-a78f-c6ab-6f9bfbdb8es3",
     "FloorNumber": "3",
     "RoomNumber": "4",
     "RoomType": ObjectId("5ae8267ed2ccda137000595b"),
     "NumberOfBeds": "5" 
   } 
   ] 
  }
```

Note that it contains embedded document RoomsDetails. Now I want fetch only one 
particular embedded document on the basis of RoomId

I have tried

```
    public function fetchRoomById()
    {
    $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate(array(
    array(
    '$match' => array(
        "_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)),
    )
    ),
    array(
    '$project' => array(
        'RoomsDetails' => array(
            '$filter' => array(
                'input' => '$RoomsDetails',
                'as' => 'Rooms',
                'cond' => array(
                    '$eq' => array('$$Rooms.RoomId', $this->RoomId)
                )
            )
        ),
            )
         )
        );
    return $cursor->toArray();
}
```

It is not returning matched embedded document, It returns main document instead of embedded document.

Please help

Comment: It returns "exactly" the matched embedded documents, and of course "inside" the parent document. Are you expecting just to return matching embedded documents "only"? Why? Because if that's the sort of query you want to do, then put all the embedded documents in another collection instead. They're meant to be embedded "because you want" the parent and child information together.

Comment: No i want only child document on the basis of RoomId field...

Answer (score 0):

I have run the filter query in my local db and it is working fine

```
db.users.aggregate(


[

    {
        $project: {
          "Name": 1,
         "Address": 1,
         "NoOfFloors":1,
         "Approved": 1,
         "SchoolId":1,
           items: {
                    $filter: {
                       input: "$RoomsDetails",
                       as: "item",
                       cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.RoomId", "80a1761f-f8ee-a78f-c6ab-6f9bfbdb8ea3" ] }
                    }
                 }
        }
    },
]);
```